# Why can't I delete a folder in my trash?

Tags: command-line, java, delete, minecraft, trash

So I downloaded a "cracked" version of Minecraft. STUPID, I know and understand the dangers. Anyway, the download put a folder called "minecraft" on my computer. it contained a .png and a .jar file. the folder was locked and ended up buying Minecraft from Mojang. Then came the problem of deleting this file. It told me I didn't have the permissions to delete the file. I used the command:

> Sudo nautilus

This managed to move the folder to trash. Now when I go to empty trash it says "ERROR WHILE DELETING". The file doesn't get deleted.... Any suggestions, tips, tricks, etc would be fantastic! :)

Comment: If the anwers below don't help, add the output of `ls -l  ~/.local/share/Trash/`

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application). You should not start graphical applications with sudo.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

`sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*`

Of course replace the * with the folder that you wish to delete or else everything in the trash will be deleted.

Comment: It worked! I'm fairly new to the linux command line, to clarify and understand    rm    is remove correct? What is    -rf    ?

Comment: `rm` is to remove, `r` stands for recursively delete and `f` attempts to (forcefully) remove the file without confirmation. See more [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/rm.1.html). In this particular case this is not much of a problem but in general be **very** careful in using this command. Also if my post helped you, accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

From a Terminal Window run the following:

sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*

Answer (score 1):

First install thunar with

```
sudo su  
apt-update  
apt-get install thunar
```

If you come from a VNC client (like mine ) then

```
xhost + 
sudo thunar
```

in the filemanager find trash and delete from the folder everything.

---

Another solution:

```
sudo mount --bind / /mnt 
sudo ncdu -x /mnt
```

Search for the desired file and delete it with the <kbd>d</kbd> key.