# I am not able to delete my folder from Trash

Tags: command-line, nautilus, directory, delete, trash

I am not able to delete a folder from my trash. It shows:

[image]

I have followed the following:
[Why can't I delete a folder in my trash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619966/why-cant-i-delete-a-folder-in-my-trash)

But, it did not help. My deleted folder shows up in 'Trash' folder not in `~/.local/share/Trash/`. I have Ubuntu 17.04 (development branch) in my machine.

Output of sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/* is:

[image]

Output of *sudo rm -rf /media/wings/B6A411BAA4117E55/.Trash-1000/* is:

[image]

Comment: Please tell us the output of  `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*`

Comment: It's nothing: blank

Comment: Did it delete the file in question ?

Comment: Please copy any output and paste into your post, no _text in image_ allowed, or is discouraged.

Comment: And that command __[sudo rm -rf /media/wings/B6A411BAA4117E55/.Trash-1000/]__  you ran __should end in a file name__ I don't see one

Comment: Thanks George. But I just followed what suggested by@RoVo. No idea.

Comment: don't use `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*` instead use `sudo /home/<username>/.local/share/Trash/*`

Comment: Thanks @Sanjeev. However, my problem was with read only file system error.... as I mentioned in question that folder is not in *~/.local/share/Trash/*. These answers did not work. I have solved it and answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to check disk for errors but *fsck* did not work too.
Then I used my Windows to

- check for errors in that drive, and
- repair.

Did reboot and everything was ok.

Answer (score 2):

The description in that article "[Why can't I delete a folder in my trash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619966/why-cant-i-delete-a-folder-in-my-trash)" works only for your local Trash. If the file you want to delete is on an external drive, you need to type

`sudo rm -rf /path/to/external-drive-mountpoint/.Trashes/*`

replace the path accordingly.

**Update**

According to the error messages, the problem exists because your external drive is mounted read only. There are many questions around here related to that problem.

Comment: I have mount point as: / ; and using $ sudo rm -rf /.trashes/* gives nothing.

Comment: I mean the mountpoint of the external drive .... something like`/media/username/hdd/`. Find out using `lsblk`

Comment: So a `right click` won't delete ?

Comment: @ RoVo, plz check the description for the output of: sudo rm -rf /path/to/external-drive-mountpoint/.Trashes/*

Comment: Okay then it's a different problem. Search for that read only file system error here, there are many questions to this problem

Comment: Thanks @RoVo. I searched for 'read only file system error'  and found an answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56852/cant-delete-edit-files-on-my-pendrive) by [Allan](http://askubuntu.com/users/6450/allan). His edit worked for me.